# How we can Sort in MongoDB on the basis array Length?

Tags: mongodb, sorting, mongoose, nosql, backend

> [There is **bidding column** in this Schema which contains array and on the basis of array length I want to sort the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0FzV.png)>

Comment: good to add the input example as text not as picture ...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
"$addFields": {
  "arrayCount": {
    $size: "$biddings"
   }
 }
},
{
 $sort: {
   arrayCount: -1
 }
}
])
```

Explained:

1. Add one more field that contain the number of elements in array
2. Sort by the newly created field

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PWsD5yg1o4D)